# Python Elasticsearch query not returning the expected results when running subsequent calls

Tags: python-2.7, elasticsearch

I am querying an elasticsearch index from python. Issue 1 is that when I change my query and rerun it, my objects in Python don't get refreshed according to my modified query. Issue 2 is that even if I see that I got some hits, no data comes through at all (eg I see I've got 85k hits, but when I put it in a dictionary, it is blank).

```
es = Elasticsearch("host:port", timeout=600, max_retries=10, revival_delay=0)


origall = es.search('esdata' ,'primary',
                {"query": 
                    {"bool": 
                        {"must_not": 
                            [{
                                "term": {"file": "original"}
                            }]
                            }
                    }
                    ,"size" : "0"}
                )

total_o = origall['hits']['total']
```

At this stage for total_o I get 110k, which is correct. Then I rerun my query after changing the size=0 to size=20, and if I want to have a look at these 20 hits, I get nothing for this:

```
orig = origall['hits']['hits']
print(orig)
```

Then I go back to my original query and change the must_not to must. In this way I should get 85k hits, but after rerunning it I still get 110k in total_o.

It is quite random when it works and when it doesn't. Sometimes I get my expected 85k hits, but then this get stuck and when I change my query back to get the 110k, it would still be 85k. Also sometimes I get data in my orig = origall['hits']['hits'], but then let's say I change the size in my query to 0, rerun it and the origall['hits']['hits'] will still give me back the data.

I use Anaconda, but tried also in Pycharm and the default Python IDLE, these behave the same. Tried to create separate ES connections for all my queries, doesn't help. Played around with cache, but no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I turned out that this was due to the firewall caching settings. Not sure what the setting was originally and what we had to change it to, but play around, it helped for me.